# Proc Report How to hide rows?

Tags: sas

I am trying to use `hidden_rows` in place of `hidden_columns`, but it doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
ods tagsets.excelxp file="spacing.xls" style=statistical
options( hidden_columns='1,2,3');

proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;

ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```

Answer (score 0):

`tagsets.excelxp` does not have an option `hidden_rows`. The tagset documentation can be written to the log window using this code:

```
ods tagsets.excelxp file="sandbox.xml" options (doc='all');
ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```

In what context are you trying to hide rows in the Proc REPORT output ? detail lines, group lines, summary lines ?